Powershell does not recognize mysql command
whenever i want to execute a mysql command in the powershell i get the follwing error message:
mysql : The name "mysql" was not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, a function, a script file or an executable program.
executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or whether the path is correct (if
is correct (if included) and repeat the process.


  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mysql:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException




Mysql is installed, or at least the client stuff. So why do i get this error? Do i have to edit the enviroment variables to make Windows recognize the installation?
For context: I'm following a Spring boot tutorial (https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql) and choosed to install docker and the corresponding mysql container using this tutorial (https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/set-up-and-configure-mysql-in-docker). I know that the author is using linux.
